# Jquery mobile : how to make list item disabled dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Please advice on how i can disable a list item(dynamically)?

Scenario is :

I have 10 list items in a list view all enabled when application start.
Now when user selects any list item i need to disable the rest of nine list item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile you can add the class `ui-state-disabled` to the anchor tag within a listitem to disable it. So to disable all other listitems when you click one of them:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $("#theList li a").on("click", function(){        
        $("#theList li a").addClass("ui-state-disabled");   
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-disabled");  
    });   

    $("#btnClear").on("click", function(){ 
        $("#theList li a").removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
    });
});
```

NOTE: theList  is the id of the UL and btnClear is the id of a separate button that removes the disabled tate from all listitems.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5n9wB/2/)**

Comment: thanks a ton.You helped me understand how jquery mobile works with a simple demo.

Answer (score 1):

`$(selector).addClass('disabled');`

Best answer I can give without more details.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Rene, you need to provide more details. A universal (not the cleanest) solution for this abstract question is:

CSS:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    /* other styles: grayed background etc. */
}
```

JS (same as previous answer):

```
$(selector).addClass('disabled');
```

This allows to make it disabled without checking its state in JavaScript upon click.

Comment: @RenéRoth yeah... missed that point. Anyway, as you pointed, the question is missing details.